# I want to call function on window unload

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, events, jquery-events

I am trying to display confirmation box using `window.confirm` on window unload event.

If a user clicks on the <kbd>OK</kbd> button on confirmation box then I want to call one function and if user clicks the <kbd>CANCEL</kbd> button then window should be get closed.

My code is:

```
<script>
        function confirmit(){
                var result=window.confirm("Are you sure?");
                if(result) {
                    // close all child windows
                } else{
                    // window should not get close
                }
            }
</script>
<body onunload='confirmit();' >
```

**But the problem is if I click on <kbd>CANCEL</kbd> button, window is getting closed.**

Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't prevent unload to stop the page from unloading. You need to bind to onbeforeunload instead. You should just return the string you want to display to the user from the event handler (note that in some browsers the string may not be displayed)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
        var msg = 'Are you sure?';
        e = e || window.event;

        if(e)
            e.returnValue = msg;

        return msg;
    }
</script>
```

[More info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload)

### JSFiddle Example here

Comment: @PaulPro.. Can you please post your jsfiddle example on jsbin, Bcoz jsfiddle is block on my network?

Answer (score 2):

change your code to this to make it work cross-browser:

```
<script>
  window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
    if (e) {
      e.returnValue = 'Do you really want to exit?';
    }

    // For Safari
    return 'Do you really want to exit?';
  };
</script>
<body>
...
```

note that this is using the [onbeforeunload-event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) ([more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907%28VS.85%29.aspx) / [view an example](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/refs/onbeforeunload.htm)) where the return-value has to be the message that should be shown to the user.

i don't know if you'll have a chance to react on the confirmation to do something after that (closing child-windows for example), but i don't think so.

Comment: @Oezi..is it possible to close child window autoomatically, when parent window is close?

Comment: if you#re opening the windows with `window.open` using the `dependent`-flag, they'll close automatically (note that this isn't supported by all browsers): http://www.google.de/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=window.open+dependent